Why is it inconceivable that a problem is in P but not in NP?
It is my understanding that if a problem has several solutions, then

the problem is in P if at least one of the solutions can be found in polynomial time,
the problem is in NP if each of the solutions can be verified in polynomial time.

If that is correct, please consider the following:
Assume that there exists a problem X which has several solutions. Some, but not all, of these solutions can be found in polynomial time. Therefore X is in P.
Furthermore, assume that some of the solutions to X can be verified in polynomial time, but other solutions cannot. Therefore X is not in NP.
If the above were true, there would exist some problems in P that are not in NP. Why is that an impossibility?
Obviously, the solutions to X that can be found in polynomial time can also be verified in polynomial time; but I don't see why solutions to X that cannot be found in polynomial time must nevertheless be verifiable in polynomial time.

P and NP are classes of decision problems (ie sets). Each instance has exactly one solution, and that solution is either "yes" or "no".
Of course one can also investigate search problems, where there can be many solutions. There is a natural counterpart to P here, which is indeed asking that some solution can be computed in polynomial time. The corresponding counterpart to NP is asking that there is a non-deterministic TM that runs in polynomial time, either outputs a solution or reports a fault depending on the non-deterministic choices, with some choices leading to a solution.
The class of searchproblems with polynomial-time decidable graph (which is what you also mention) is not really a nice complexity class, and indeed does not constitute a superset of the polytime-solvable search problems.

Your definition of NP seems to be incorrect.

A language $L\subseteq \{0,1\}^*$ is in NP if there exists a polynomial $p:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ and a polynomial-time TM $M$ (called the verifier for $L$) such that for every $x\in \{0,1\}^*$,$$x\in L \iff \exists u\in \{0,1\}^{p(|x|)} s.t. M(x,u)=1$$

This definition is from Arora and Barak, it means that a problem is in NP if it exists a solution $u$, having polynomial length to $x$, can be verified in polynomial time.
